# T-SQL - How to split (char separated) string into rows and columns

Tags: t-sql, string

What is the best way to split a char separated string into rows and columns?

Here is my input string:

```
!1;100;10;200;0;500;2;1000;30!2;100;3;500;1;2000;5
```

And here is my desired output table:

```
Id  Value  Count
1   100    10
1   200    0
1   500    2
1   1000   30
2   100    3
2   500    1
2   2000   5
```

Best Regards,

Comment: this has been answered before, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string

Comment: That's a fairly basic split.  This one requires two levels of splitting and breaking the output up.  First split by ! then split the result set up using the first value as Id then the rest get paired up to make the Value and Count columns.

Answer (score 2):

It is not neccesary to modify Jeff Moden's function. I have devised a little bit sophisticated way of achieving the result just using the original function.

First Here it is the original Moden's function:
(Source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

And the query for obtaining the required result (I have created a CTE just for clarity)

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000)
SET @string = '!1;100;10;200;0;500;2;1000;30!2;100;3;500;1;2000;5'

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(A.Item,1,CHARINDEX(';',A.Item)-1) As Id, 
B.Item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, '!') AS A
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(A.Item, ';') AS B
WHERE A.Item <> '' --to avoid blank first row because the first !
)

SELECT Id, [Value], [Count]
FROM
(
SELECT Id, Item As [Value], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) As RowNumber,
LEAD(Item,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) As [Count]
FROM CTE
) As T
WHERE RowNumber % 2 = 0
```

**EDITED:**
I realized that my solution assummed that **id** value was ordered or that the order in the original string was not neccesary to be preserved in the result. Below the general solution (note that I changed the first number in the string for testing the situation)

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000)
SET @string = '!3;100;10;200;0;500;2;1000;30!2;100;3;500;1;2000;5'
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) As RN,
CAST(SUBSTRING(A.Item,1,CHARINDEX(';',A.Item)-1) AS Varchar(400)) As Id, 
B.Item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, '!') AS A
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(A.Item, ';') AS B
WHERE A.Item <> '' --to avoid blank first row because the first !
)

SELECT Id, [Value], [Count]
FROM
(
SELECT Id, Item As [Value], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) As RowNumber,
LEAD(Item,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) As [Count]
,FIRST_VALUE(RN) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) AS FV
FROM CTE
) As T
WHERE RowNumber % 2 = 0
ORDER BY FV
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31ccd/3

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Moden created a splitter function over on www.SQLServerCentral.com called [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  It takes two parameters @pString (the string to split) & @pDelimiter (the delimiter, in your case ;).

However in your case you aren't doing a straight up split, so it will have to be modified a little bit.  In fact we have to do two different types of splits.  The first a normal one to split on ! and the second a modified one to get the different rows using the first value as the first column and the rest split in pairs, one pair per row.

Test code first

```
DECLARE @splitstring varchar(8000)
SET @splitstring = '!1;100;10;200;0;500;2;1000;30!2;100;3;500;1;2000;5'
-- First use the original function to split out the groups.
-- The STUFF function removes the first ! since this is a split function
-- and if it's left we get a blank line.
SELECT FinalDelim.* 
FROM DelimitedSplit8K(STUFF(@splitstring,1,1,''),'!') AS FirstDelim
-- Here we CROSS APPLY the modified version over each of the original splits
CROSS APPLY ModifiedDelimitedSplit8K(FirstDelim.Item,';') AS FinalDelim
GO
```

And here is the ModifiedDelimitedSplit8K code.

```
-- Based Jeff Modem's original script
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ModifiedDelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                ),
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
-- Putting this in it's own CTE since we need ItemNumber 1 for all of the rows
cteSplitString(ItemNumber, Item) AS (
     SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
            Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
    FROM cteLen l)
SELECT cteItem1.Item AS Id,
    cteItem2.Value,
    cteItem2.Count
FROM (SELECT Item FROM cteSplitString WHERE ItemNumber = 1) AS cteItem1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber%2 = 0 THEN Item ELSE NULL END) AS Value,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber%2 = 1 THEN Item ELSE NULL END) AS Count
            FROM cteSplitString 
            WHERE ItemNumber > 1
            GROUP BY ItemNumber/2) AS cteItem2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solutuion. But since your proposal was a bit particular I decided to create an **ad-hoc** solution. It was fun.
Can be tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/623

```
    declare @string varchar(max) 
    set @string = '!1;100;10;200;0;500;2;1000;30!2;100;3;500;1;2000;5'

    declare @t1  table (row varchar(max))

    declare @end int 
    set @end = 1

    set @string = substring ( @string ,2, len(@string))
    while charindex ( '!' ,@string,1) > 0
    begin
        set @end = charindex ( '!' ,@string,1)
        insert into @t1 (row) values (substring ( @string ,1, @end - 1))
        set @string = substring ( @string ,@end+1, len(@string))
    end
    set @end = len(@string)

    insert into @t1 (row) values (substring ( @string ,1, @end))

    declare cur cursor for select * from @t1
    open cur

    declare @row varchar(max)
    fetch next from cur into @row
    declare @result table
    (id varchar(max), [value] varchar(max), [count] varchar(max))
    declare @id varchar(max), @value varchar(max), @count varchar(max)
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @end = charindex( ';' ,@row)
        set @id = substring(@row,1,@end-1)
        set @row = substring(@row,@end +1,len(@row))
        while len(@row) > 0 
        begin
            set @end = charindex( ';' ,@row)
            set @value = substring(@row,1,@end-1)
            set @row = substring(@row,@end +1,len(@row))
            set @end = charindex( ';' ,@row)
            if @end > 0 
            begin
                set @count = substring(@row,1,@end-1)
                set @row = substring(@row,@end +1,len(@row))
                set @end = charindex( ';' ,@row)
            end
            else 
            begin
                set @count = substring(@row,1,len(@row))
                set @row = ''
            end
            insert into @result (id, [value], [count]) values (@id, @value, @count)
        end
        fetch next from cur into @row   
    end
close cur
deallocate cur   
select * from @result
```